# gulp - Compass failed: You must compile individual stylesheets from the project directory.

Tags: gulp, compass-sass, singularitygs

I am using gulpjs and i wanted to compass

but i am getting following error

```
[gulp] gulp-notify: [Error running Gulp] Compass failed
[gulp] You must compile individual stylesheets from the project directory.
```

This is my config.rb

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "app/assets/src/stylesheets"
sass_dir = "app/assets/stylesheets"
images_dir = "app/assets/images"
javascripts_dir = "app/assets/javascript"
```

This is my gulp.js

```
.pipe($.compass({
    config_file: './config.rb',
    css: 'app/assets/src/stylesheets',
    sass: 'app/assets/stylesheets',
    require: [
    'bourbon',
    'singularitygs'
    ],bundle_exec:true}))
```

Comment: does it work when you just run `compass compile` without gulp?

Answer (score 3):

(Can't comment because of reputation)

Do you use .scss or .sass files ? If you're using .sass only, here's a working code, but not with compass :

```
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');

gulp.task('compile-sass-task', function() {
    return gulp.src(config.path.sass+"/main.sass")
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.path.css));
});
```

I'll edit if you provide more informations. And why use compass instead of gulp-sass for example ?

Comment: Compass provides a lot of features that vanilla Sass doesn't have. The most important of them is support for Compass extensions (Sass libs distributed) via RubyGems.